# android support libraries causing errors with legal and valid methods

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, android-notifications, android-appcompat

I am using android support library v4 and v7 but these libraries causing errors i don't know what is wrong here.

I am getting errors in NotificationCompat, NotificationManager, ViewCompat

All the things i am using from support libraries are causing errors while generating apk.

here is my gradle file

```
compile project(':listViewLibrary')

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v3.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.7.jar')
compile files('libs/asmack-android-6-0.8.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

compile project(':library')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
compile 'com.github.frank-zhu:pullzoomview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'
```

and here is the code where i am getting errors

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.UpdateAppearance;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewDebug.CapturedViewProperty;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.TextView;

class FadeyTextView extends TextView {
private Interpolator mInterpolator;
private long mStart, mDurationPerLetter;
private boolean mAnimating = false;
private SpannableString mFadeyText;
private CharSequence mText;

public FadeyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public FadeyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

@SuppressLint("Instantiatable") public FadeyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    // Set defaults
    mInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    mDurationPerLetter = 250;
}

public void setInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
    mInterpolator = interpolator;
}

public void setDurationPerLetter(long durationPerLetter) {
    mDurationPerLetter = durationPerLetter;
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    mText = text;
    mFadeyText = new SpannableString(text);
    FadeyLetterSpan[] letters = mFadeyText.getSpans(0, mFadeyText.length(),
            FadeyLetterSpan.class);
    for (FadeyLetterSpan letter : letters) {
        mFadeyText.removeSpan(letter);
    }
    final int length = mFadeyText.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        mFadeyText.setSpan(new FadeyLetterSpan(), i, i + 1,
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    super.setText(mFadeyText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    mAnimating = true;
    mStart = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
}

@Override
@CapturedViewProperty
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}

public boolean isAnimating() {
    return mAnimating;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mAnimating) {
        long mDelta = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() - mStart;
        FadeyLetterSpan[] letters = mFadeyText.getSpans(0,
                mFadeyText.length(), FadeyLetterSpan.class);
        final int length = letters.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            FadeyLetterSpan letter = letters[i];
            float delta = (float) Math.max(Math
                    .min((mDelta - (i * mDurationPerLetter)),
                            mDurationPerLetter), 0);
            letter.setAlpha(mInterpolator.getInterpolation(delta
                    / (float) mDurationPerLetter));
        }
        if (mDelta < mDurationPerLetter * length) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        } else {
            mAnimating = false;
        }
    }
}

private class FadeyLetterSpan extends CharacterStyle implements
        UpdateAppearance {
    private float mAlpha = 0.0f;

    public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
        mAlpha = Math.max(Math.min(alpha, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        int color = ((int) (0xFF * mAlpha) << 24)
                | (tp.getColor() & 0x00FFFFFF);
        tp.setColor(color);
    }
}
}
```

and second file

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

mNotificationManager.notify(999, mBuilder.build());
```

error log

```
/Users/Punit/Downloads/xyz/src/main/java/app/date/FadeyTextView.java
Error:(72, 13) error: cannot find symbol method postInvalidateOnAnimation(FadeyTextView)
Error:(102, 15) error: cannot find symbol method postInvalidateOnAnimation(FadeyTextView)
/Users/Punit/Downloads/xyz/src/main/java/app/date/PushService.java
Error:(169, 21) error: cannot find symbol class InboxStyle
Error:(169, 68) error: cannot find symbol class InboxStyle
Error:(211, 44) error: cannot find symbol method build()
```